# Tensor Flow with GPU support

Tags: tensorflow

```
TUF-Gaming-FX505DT-FX505DT:/home/jithin# lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev ff)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c2)
```

I have recently ordered a gtx 3060 + R5 7600x system , it will reach in 1-2 week before it arrives i thought to try tensorflow on my laptop ,i currently have an asus tuf fx 505DT laptop with

i am trying to install tensorflow with gpu support , but i am facing many issues from choosing which cuda, cudnn , gcc version to choose and how to install them. i am on ubuntu 22.04. Can some one post all steps , including version to install.

Comment: There are 89 answers from a search of this site for cuda tensorflow cudnn -- have you looked at them?  Basically, your card may have limits on CUDA support, then cudnn and tensorflow may each have version recommendations/limitations.  A matter of finding a compatible set.

Comment: I have attempted to install TensorFlow with GPU support multiple times, but have been unsuccessful so far. I tried following instructions that were specific to other GPUs, but adapted them to my own using a version of CUDA that I found on other websites. However, all of these instructions seem to be outdated. Currently, TensorFlow does not have a separate tensorflow-gpu package, as it has been merged into the main TensorFlow package. Unfortunately, the instructions I tried were mostly for tensorflow-gpu and the other ones I found did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following sequence of commands and it worked -
Install TensorFlow-2.11.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 with GPU (RTX 3080ti and RTX 2060) support

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
nvcc --version
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --upgrade pip
nvcc --version
nvidia-smi
pip3 --version
sudo pip3 install nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96
sudo pip3 install tensorflow==2.11.0
sudo apt install nvidia-cudnn
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```